# How to add attributes to input fields in JSP

Tags: forms, jsp, properties, attributes

How can I add the following attributes:

1. placeholder="text here"
2. required
3. data-parsley-type="number"
4. checked (only for he radio)

To the following inputs in a form:

```
<html:text property="text" value="text" />
<html:radio property="radio" value="1" />
<html:select property="text" value="1" />
```